# Installing rbenv on VPS, Permission Denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, permissions, rbenv

I got a permission denied error when I tried the following while installing rbenv. I'm trying to set up my VPS environment to deploy my rails app.

```
deployer@max:~$ curl https://raw.github.com/fesplugas/rbenv-installer/master/bin/rbenv-installer | bash
bash: /usr/bin/curl: permission denied
```

curl is already installed. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Have you looked at this http://superuser.com/questions/171518/curl-works-only-as-root?

Comment: reinstalling curl fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, I had to

1) go back to root with

```
su root
cd
```

2) reinstall curl

```
sudo apt-get purge curl libcurl3
sudo apt-get install curl
```

3) go back to deployer

```
su deployer
cd
```

4) install rbenv

```
curl https://raw.github.com/fesplugas/rbenv-installer/master/bin/rbenv-installer | bash
```